# Symfony. PostgressSQL connection

Tags: postgresql, symfony, containers

В разных контейнерах находятся база и Симфони.
Файл `.env` :

```
DATABASE_URL=pgsql://api_user:@GR&G)*(@HR#&RH@postgres:5432/portmone
```

docker-composer:

```
php-fpm:
  build:
    context: ./docker/php-fpm
  volumes:
    - ./docker/php-fpm/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
    - ./:/var/www
  expose:
    - "9000"
postgres:
  build: ./docker/postgres
  volumes:
    - ./docker/postgres/entrypoint-initdb.d:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
  ports:
    - "5432:5432"
  environment:
    - POSTGRES_DB=portmonez
    - POSTGRES_USER=api_user
    - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=@GR&G)*(@HR#&RH
```

postgres/entrypoint_db.d/createdb.sh

```
 psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 --username "$POSTGRES_USER" --dbname "$POSTGRES_DB" <<-EOSQL
 CREATE USER portmone WITH PASSWORD '@GR&G)*(@HR#&RH';
 CREATE DATABASE portmone;
 GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE portmone TO portmone;
 EOSQL
```

Получаю ошибку: `Connection does not contain a 'path' or 'dbname' parameter and cannot be dropped.`
Что не так?

Comment: видимо __@__ в пароле воспринимается как разделитель хоста

Comment: @DmitryKozlov, да, Вы правы, а так же пришлось убрать символ `#`. Добавте как ответ)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном случае неэкранированные символы в пароле воспринимаются как служебные разделители. Если строки все же должны содержать данные символы, то их можно вынести в переменные, заключив в апострофы https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv#variable-substitution

```
DBUSER='api_user'
DBPASSWORD='@GR&G)*(@HR#&RH'
DATABASE_URL=pgsql://${DBUSER}:${DBPASSWORD}@postgres:5432/portmone
```